# Passing values back to DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, master-detail

I have made a MasterDetailView application. In the TableView I have list of employees and on the detailView  I have a Welcome screen with the employee details and other details. When I click on any employee, through navigatorController, I call a view with a form, where I have a button to upload the details of the form to the server. I want to display the uploaded date in the welcome screen. I am saving the date in userDefaults and but once I navigate back, non of my methods get called, viewDidlLoad or viewDidApper of DetailViewController, so I can display the uploaded date in my welcome screen. Please help me on how to pass the values back to the DetailViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You could post an NSNotification. But the best solution is to set up a delegate relationship between the "view with a form" and the "welcome screen", so that the one can actually talk directly to the other and pass the values back.

Look at the structure of Apple's "Utility app" project template to see how to set up a delegate relationship between two view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

In A MasterDetailView application the MasterViewController is always the first view owned by the SplitViewController.

So, one way to communicate back is:

```
YourMasterViewController * yourMasterViewController = (YourMasterViewController*)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] topViewController];
[yourMasterViewController someMethodLikeUploadCompleted];
```

I've used that to let detail views send messages back to the master.